# Twisted unit tests run via nose?

Tags: python, twisted, nose, nosetests

Our Python code base uses nose to run all unit tests, and I'm trying to use nose.twistedtools to make all the tests run, but they're all hanging at shutdown.  Any help straightening this out would be great.  Here's a simple test that hangs:

```
from nose.twistedtools import deferred
from twisted.internet.defer import Deferred

@deferred(timeout=1)
def test_rudimentary():
    def done(_ignored):
        print "DONE"

    defer = Deferred()
    defer.addCallback(done)
    return defer
```

The invocation and output looks like this:

```
$ nosetests test_simple.py 
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_simple.test_rudimentary
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/<ENV>/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/case.py", line 197, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "/home/<ENV>/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/twistedtools.py", line 165, in wrapper
    % timeout)
TimeExpired: timeout expired before end of test (1.000000 s.)

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 1.001s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

If I don't set a timeout, the test hangs forever.

Comment: nose is not a recommended test runner for Twisted-based unit tests.  Failing that, returning Deferreds from test methods is not a recommended way of writing tests for Twisted-based code.

Comment: Any good docs on this?  The Twisted docs on doing TDD are really, really weak.  Is Trial the right answer?  unit2?

Comment: trial is a good answer, yes.  I haven't tried unittest2, but since it is still supposed to be an xUnit-style library it might work.  Here's a document about how to write unit tests for Twisted-using code - http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/trial.html - there's lots more it doesn't cover, but at least it's a start.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is responsible for calling defer.callback/errback (most probably indirectly). Try:

```
reactor.callLater(0.1, defer.callback)
return defer
```